# I m trying to show Y and Y2 in bar chart but in y2 axis it is showing only 0 to 1 value in range in c3.js

Tags: javascript, c#, c3.js

I am generating dynamic names for both columns and data 1, data 2. Now I'm trying to show `Y` and `Y2` in bar chart but in `y2` axis it is showing only `0` to `1` value in range in `c3` js

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var FunnelGrowthACVColumns = [];
    var FunnelGrowthRatioColumns = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= data.data.FunnelGrowthMartix.length - 1; i++) {
        FunnelGrowthACVColumns.push(parseFloat(data.data.FunnelGrowthMartix[i].FunnelGrowth));
        FunnelGrowthRatioColumns.push(parseFloat(data.data.FunnelGrowthMartix[i].Per_Growth));
    }

    var titleFunnelGrowthACV = data.data.FunnelGrowthMartix[0].Title + 'ACV';
    var titleFunnelGrowthRatio = data.data.FunnelGrowthMartix[0].Title +'Ratio';

    var chart1 = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chartContainer2',
        data: {
            columns: [                               
                [titleFunnelGrowthACV].concat(FunnelGrowthACVColumns),                               
                [titleFunnelGrowthRatio].concat(FunnelGrowthRatioColumns),
            ],
            type: 'bar',
            labels: true,
            axes: {
                titleFunnelGrowthACV: 'y',
                titleFunnelGrowthRatio: 'y2'
            },
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                categories: MartixMonths,
            },
            y: {
                label: {
                    text: 'Unit (In Rs Crores)',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                },
            },
            y2: {
                show: true,
            }
        },
        color: {
            pattern: ['#2ca02c', '#0000ff']
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.5
            },
            tooltip: {
                format: {
                    title: function (d) { return 'Data' + d; },
                },
                grouped: true
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'center'
            }
        }
    });
    $('#chartContainer2').append(chart1.element);
});
```

Value of y axis are changing for both data 1 and data 2.

[data2_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPRA6.jpg)
[data1_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIWAx.jpg)
[data1&data2_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHto5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The range 0..1 in the second y axis tends to happen when a series hasn't been bound to it.

Looking at your screenshots I suspect you've just got a typo. The tooltips in the screenshots show the series names "FunnelGrowthACV" and "FunnelGrowthRatio", but you're asking for

```
axes: {
        titleFunnelGrowthACV: 'y',
        titleFunnelGrowthRatio: 'y2'
},
```

change it to

```
axes: {
        FunnelGrowthACV: 'y',
        FunnelGrowthRatio: 'y2'
},
```

and see if that now works

Comment: Thanks ..I Tried but it's  not working.
As it will not find any column name as axes.